# Hostile Mobs not Spawning in An Area (Edited with WorldEdit)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

I'm playing v1.16 with Forge v36.1.0.
I used WorldEdit on a previously-played world to edit a selection - I regenerated the blocks in it and change the biome vertically (made a 2D selection and `//expand`ed with `vert`).

Now no hostile mobs spawn in that area.

I can confirm that mobs spawn outside of what I remember the selection is - both on the ground, below ground and above ground - but not inside that area.

It didn't happen before the editing with `WorldEdit` but I can't verify that because I was playing on `Peaceful` for almost all the time.

I tried contracted WorldEdit developers but they didn't know why that happened and thought this doesn't have to do with WorldEdit.

Can anyone please help me debug this? I don't even know where to start.

I used `/gamerule doMobSpawning true` but it didn't help.

Update: I made 2 almost-identical hollow boxes of width 1 (boxes whose walls are 1 blocks-wide) in area where I did see hostile mobs spawn naturally. The light levels inside of them were 0 - hostile mobs spawn at 7 or less to my understanding.
One of them I made with WorldEdit with `//replace` and various `//expand`s and `//contract`s, and one of them I made manually by placing blocks.
The one I made with WorldEdit didn't have mobs spawn inside, and the one I built manually did.

So I'm pretty sure it has to do with WorldEdit causing this.

Comment: While I can't say for sure, it's possible that when you used WorldEdit it erased, or did not put, any mob spawn points into the section you edited.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that there are mob spawns points.
Do you know how can I view (and edit) spawn points in v1.16? I tried doing some googling but didn't find information on how to do that. I want to check the idea you hypothesized.

Comment: @Kadima I talked to a WorldEdit developer and they said that mob spawn points "isn't a thing". What's your background in regards to Minecraft?

Comment: Minimal. I don't play, but a lot of my friends do and talk to me about it. I thought one of them had mentioned something like that, but I could easily be wrong. That's why I started the comment with "I can't say for sure, it's possible..." instead of providing an answer.

Comment: Oh, I thought the uncertainty is due to you not having much information.
Thanks, I'm keeping on investigating this.